# Trying to use patch to mock BlobServiceClient but the real class is called instead

Tags: python, pytest, azure-blob-storage

I have the following class

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

class FooContainer:
    def __init__(self, project_id, account_url, sas_token):
        service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=sas_token)
        self.container_client = service_client.get_container_client("foo")
        self.blob_name = f"{project_id}.foo.json"

    def upload(self, text):
        print(text)
        self.container_client.upload_blob(name=self.blob_name, data=text, overwrite=True)
```

I want to test that when I call `upload` that `container_client.upload_blob` is called correctly, so I have the following test

```
from unittest import mock
from foo_container import FooContainer

@mock.patch('azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient', autospec=True)
def test_init(mockBlobServiceClient):
    container = FooContainer("x", "y", "z")

    container.upload("some text")

    mockBlobServiceClient.container_client.upload_blob.assert_called_with(
        name="x.foo.json", data="some text", overwrite=True)
```

When I run the test with `python3 -m pytest test_foo_container.py` it looks like BlobServiceClient is not mocked at all as the test fails with `FAILED test_foo_container.py::test_init - ValueError: Unable to determine account name for shared key credential.`

The full failure log is

```
================================================================================================= FAILURES =================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_init _________________________________________________________________________________________________

mockBlobServiceClient = <MagicMock name='BlobServiceClient' spec='BlobServiceClient' id='4572408592'>

    @mock.patch('azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient', autospec=True)
    def test_init(mockBlobServiceClient):
>       container = FooContainer("x", "y", "z")

test_foo_container.py:6: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
foo_container.py:5: in __init__
    service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=sas_token)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_service_client.py:126: in __init__
    super(BlobServiceClient, self).__init__(parsed_url, service='blob', credential=credential, **kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/base_client.py:90: in __init__
    self.credential = format_shared_key_credential(account, credential)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

account = ['y'], credential = 'z'

    def format_shared_key_credential(account, credential):
        if isinstance(credential, six.string_types):
            if len(account) < 2:
>               raise ValueError("Unable to determine account name for shared key credential.")
E               ValueError: Unable to determine account name for shared key credential.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/base_client.py:324: ValueError
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is `BlobServiceClient` not mocked and the real class used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mocking, we have to specify *the module where the mock will be used*, not just the module that *will be mocked*.

A self-contained example:

**src/hello.py**

```py
def do_something_under_test():
    open('my_file')
```

**test/test_hello.py**

```py
import mock

from src import hello


@mock.patch('src.hello.open')
def test_hello(mock_open):
    hello.do_something_under_test()
    mock_open.assert_called_with('my_file')
```

Note that we don't mock `open`, but `src.hello.open`.

In your example, try to preface the `@mock.patch('azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient')` with the module `FooContainer` is defined in: `foo_container`.

I suspect the answer will be `@mock.patch('foo_container.BlobServiceClient')` -- this is because of how you are importing the `BlobServiceClient`.

Comment: Excellent, you've put me on the right path. I had previously tried `@mock.patch('foo_container.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient')` which resulted in ` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo_container.azure'; 'foo_container' is not a package`. It hadn't occurred to me to do `@mock.patch('foo_container.BlobServiceClient')`. Running the test with that gives me `AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'container_client'`. I can see why that is happening. Thanks for your help.