# Unit test for spark read/write function to azure data lake mount path

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pytest, azure-storage-account

I am very new to unit testing and I need to write a unit test for spark read/write function.

I have a function as below for example:

```
def read_file(path, format, logger):
   df = spark.read.load(path, format = format)
   etc.....
   return df
```

*note : the path is mounted.*

now I need to write unit test for this function / **mock adls location**.

I have checked below link which is using patch to mock blobServiceClient but I am not sure whether this is useful to me as it is using open function of python.

[Trying to use patch to mock BlobServiceClient but the real class is called instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622820/trying-to-use-patch-to-mock-blobserviceclient-but-the-real-class-is-called-inste)

Is it even possible to mock adls and if so how?

Can anyone please help me in this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproducible example of your code? What should we mock exactly? What is ``adls`` ?

Comment: adls is azure data lake storage and I want to mock that as I am reading a file from alds only and it is mounted.

Comment: Is your unit test purpose to test access to ADLS or to test functionality. Can you provide a local path instead?

Comment: After searching a lot I figured that I can test access to ADLS by using @mock.patch(BlobServiceClient) but here now I want to test the functionality and the requirement is that the function should be self contained, it shouldn't make any connections and that's why I need to mock the path whether it is local or mounted.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez if you have any idea how to do it, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure HDFS is available locally. If you are running your tests on Windows make sure you read this readme https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

This repo makes a reference to this other repo for newer versions. These 2 github contributors are part of the Hadoop team and these are the binaries I use for my local environment.

Once this setup is complete you can pass local paths. They can be local linux or windows paths.

Also read this article to correctly set PATH items for hadoop binaries: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-hadoop-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-access0ljava-lang-stringiz/?msclkid=4333eb3bc05d11ecb99904c712581198